# Can Geoserver pass visibility information to Accumulo

Tags: geoserver, security, authentication

I have created a plug-in which allows my Geoserver to retrieve data from an Accumulo datastore.  I want to enable the visibility cell in Accumulo to only return data based on information that the Geoserver received about the user's visibility access.  Has anybody ever come across a similar problem or have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: can you add something about how visibility works on Accumulo?

Comment: Visiblity is just a column that specifies a user's access rights.  User must match the values in the column

Comment: could probably use a CQL filter then - intercept incoming requests and rewrite them to add the filter